# which one is correct; "Ministry of Interior" or "Ministry of the Interior"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I see both of them are used. In dictionaries (cambridge, collins), it has "the" whereas I have seen it used without "the" in many other places.

So, which one is correct?  "Ministry of Interior" or "Ministry of the Interior"?

Regards,

Comment: Proper names are determined by the political entity involved. Grammar is not relevant since they can call it whatever they want. If you mean a generic job description, then don't capitalize it.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on the country's convention, since it's a matter of translation.

[Saudi Arabia](https://www.moi.gov.sa/wps/portal/Home/Home), [Pakistan](https://www.interior.gov.pk), [Cyprus](http://www.moi.gov.cy/moi/moi.nsf/index_en/index_en?OpenDocument) and [Hungary](http://www.kormany.hu/en/ministry-of-interior) have a Ministry of Interior.

[Latvia](http://www.iem.gov.lv/eng/), [Finland](http://intermin.fi/en/frontpage), [Russia](http://government.ru/en/department/86/events/) and [Taiwan](https://www.moi.gov.tw/english/) have a Ministry of the Interior.

The [U.S.](https://www.doi.gov) has a Department of the Interior, but it does different jobs than other interior ministries.